# Why is it giving error in module part1?

Tags: verilog

In my previous question I said that I was asked to design a bottling system that fills bottles with the desired number of tablets. In part1 of my project, the user will press the button on FPGA to identify how many tablets will be put in the each bottle and the desired number will be displayed.This is the code of part 1 I have written for my project and I have no idea why it is giving errors in module part1.

```
module count(clk,clr,cntEn,dout);
    input clk,clr,cntEn;
    output reg [8:0] dout ;

    always@(posedge clk)
    begin
      if(clr) 
        dout<=0;
      else if(cntEn)
        dout<=dout+1;
    end

endmodule


module sevenseg(num,dout);
    input      [3:0] num;
    output reg [6:0] dout;

    always@(*) begin
    case(num)
        0:dout=7'b1111110;
        1:dout=7'b1100000;
        2:dout=7'b1011011;
        3:dout=7'b1001111;
        4:dout=7'b1100110;
        5:dout=7'b1101101;
        6:dout=7'b1111101;
        7:dout=7'b0000111;
        8:dout=7'b1111111;
        9:dout=7'b1101111;
    endcase
end

endmodule


module part1(clk,clr,cntEn,dout);
    input   clk, clr, cntEn;
    output  dout;
    wire    w1;

    begin
        count    count_1   (clk, clr, cntEn, w1);
        sevenseg sevenseg_1(w1,  dout );
    end

endmodule
```

Comment: ERROR:HDLCompilers:26 - "part1.v" line 54 expecting 'endmodule', found 'begin'

Comment: Within module 'part1', why is the instantiation of your two modules, sevenseg & count, within a 'begin - end' block?

Comment: I have done so because I remember we have done an experiment in the lab with gates and in the main module we wrote those modules within  a begin-end blocks.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The error was pointed out byljk07, the begin end in module 1 are not required, some parsers might just ignore them others will throw an error. it should be:

```
module part1(clk,clr,cntEn,dout);
  input   clk, clr, cntEn;
  output  dout;
  wire    w1;

  count    count_1   (clk, clr, cntEn, w1);
  sevenseg sevenseg_1(w1,  dout );

endmodule
```

I think it is also worth pointing out that unless your constrained to Verilog-95 then adopting an ANSI style port declaration is preferred, as it lead to easier to maintain code.

```
module part1(
  input   clk, clr, cntEn,
  output  dout
);
  wire    w1;

  count    count_1   (clk, clr, cntEn, w1);
  sevenseg sevenseg_1(w1,  dout );

endmodule
```

Module sevenseg also has an incomplete case statement which will lead to implied latches. either add a default or fully specify the output for all options of num:

```
module sevenseg(num,dout);
  input      [3:0] num;
  output reg [6:0] dout;

  always @(*) begin
    case(num)
      0:dout=7'b1111110;
      1:dout=7'b1100000;
      2:dout=7'b1011011;
      3:dout=7'b1001111;
      4:dout=7'b1100110;
      5:dout=7'b1101101;
      6:dout=7'b1111101;
      7:dout=7'b0000111;
      8:dout=7'b1111111;
      9:dout=7'b1101111;
      default: dout='b0;
    endcase
  end
endmodule
```